# Pass protractor arguments through npm using maven

Tags: maven, npm, protractor

I have a package.json file with following script

```
"scripts": {
    "protractor": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor src/test/conf.js --params.port=9080"
  }
```

And a maven `<execution>` as follows and this works fine

```
           <execution>
            <id>Run Tests</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run protractor</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
```

But when i try the following `<execution>` it fails

```
      <execution>
        <id>Run e2e Tests</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>npm</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <arguments>run protractor --params.port=9080</arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
```

How do i pass the port number as protractor arguments through maven arguments?